# How to make my webview app open url push notifications?

Tags: android, webview, push-notification, onesignal

I have a webview app and add OneSignal push notification to it and it works fine.

But when I send a push notification with a url to open in the app it instead opens in the browser.

Is there away to make url push notifications open in the app not the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

The Launch URL setting can only open market:// and web links in a web browser. If you need to open the url inside your app you will need to a click handler and additional data to the notification to open it inside your app.

Add a custom key under Options>"Additional Data" on the New Message page on the OneSignal dashboard. Or add 'data' if your using [create notification](http://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/notifications-create-notification) REST API POST call. Next, follow OneSignal's [3. Add Optional NotificationOpenedHandler](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-studio-sdk-installation#3-add-optional-notificationopenedhandler) to process the additionalData `JSONObject` and check for your custom URL key where you can then direct your webview to the url.

Comment: In OneSignal the told me to add openURL key to NotificationOpenedHadler and the value will be the url so how and where to put this line in NotificationOpenedHadler                                                                    String url = additionalData.get("openURL"):                                                                            Thank you very much